# SignalR - SQL Permissions other than dbo

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, permissions, signalr

We have a ASP.Net MVC application that uses SignalR and SQL Dependency to display the records in a SQL table.

Every time the page is accessed, a SQL SP with a guid is created. This requires the user running the app pool of the MVC application to be a dbo on SQL database. Is there any way to achieve the same functionality without giving the user dbo permission?

Regards,
Shilpa

Comment: What is real scemario? I don't get. You create new sp on each page request?

Comment: Not really. SignalR creates the SP internally when ever the page is loaded. If the app pool account doesn't have sufficient permissions, the SP doesn't get created/executed and hence the data is not displayed on the page

Comment: @ShilpaNagavara were you able to figure this out?